# round the values of a column in r/csv

Tags: r, csv

I did replace the NAs in a column in my data frame:

```
> titanic3$age[which(is.na(titanic3$age))] <- 
mean(as.numeric(titanic3$age),na.rm=T)

> is.numeric(titanic3$age)
[1] TRUE

> round(titanic3$age, 0)
 [1] 29  1  2 30 25 48 63 39 53


> str(titanic3$age)
  num [1:1309] 29 0.917 2 30 25 ...
```

When I try to round the values it doesn't work in the .csv. Only in the console.

In the .csv I have 5 digits. It looks like this:

```
age
29.00000
 0.91670
 2.00000
30.00000
25.00000
.
.
.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why would rounding numbers in R have anything to do with your CSV?

Comment: When I replaced the NA´s of my column with the mean of the column I could see it in the .csv. Why I don't see the result of the round() function in the .csv?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by showing us some data.

Comment: Can you please share your .csv dataset for the better clarity?

Comment: It looks like you didn't reassign the rounded values back into your dataset. Try `titanic3$age <- round(titanic3$age, 0)`?